# Sampling DC and AC components of capacitive sensor

Tags: sensor, analog, adc, capacitance, mems

I'm using a MEMS capacitive pressure sensor [SCB10H](https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/gyro/element/pressure/datasheet_scb10h_.ashx?la=en-gb). As I understand it, I can wire it up in one of two ways. Either I can measure the absolute capacitance using a chip like the TI [FDC1004](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/snoscy5). In this case, my sample rate is limited to what the chip offers.

Or I can wire it up like a microphone, amplify the signal and sample it as fast as I like using an ADC.

In my application, I am interested in measuring both the absolute pressure with a sample rate of 1kHz, and the arrival time of small pressure pulses to within about 1 micro second or so.

Am I right in thinking that the two measurement techniques are incompatible? If so, how can I measure the absolute pressure, and also sample the AC component at high speed?

Comment: I didn't work with this sensor. I think you can read capacitance for example in Capacitor Wheatstone Bridge but your sensor says "Lowest mechanical resonance frequency of the diaphragm 450 kHz". if you apply a small pressure pulse, that may generate resonance in sensor and you have a mistake in measurement. 1 kHz sampling is achievable.

Comment: if you read the capacitor with constant current and measuring the voltage. then i_cte = dv/dt * C + v * dC/dt (from C*v = Q) . after pulse actuates the sensor you have dC/dt and this generates dv/dt. where v fluctuate then you have step in the capacitance. all time where C not ring you can measure C with C * delta(v)/delta(t)=i_cte